# How can I provide safety template for user to modify with python?

Tags: python, web, templates

I am building a multi-user web application. Each user can have their own site under my application. I am considering how to allow user to modify template without security problem? I have evaluated some python template engine. For example, genshi, it is a pretty wonderful template engine, but however it might be dangerous to allow user to modify genshi template. It have a syntax like this:

```
<?python

?>
```

This syntax allow you run whatever you want python can do. I notice that it seems can be shutdown by passing some parameter. But there are still a lots of potential problems. For example, user can access build-in functions, and methods of passed variables. For example, if I pass a ORM object to template. It might contain some method and variable that I don't want to allow user touch it. May like this:

```
site.metadata.connection.execute("drop table xxx")
```

So my question is how can I allow user to modify template of their site without security problems? Any python template engine can be used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Django templte engine](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#topics-templates).  It does not support execution of arbitrary python code and all accessible variables must be passed into template explicity.  This should be pretty good foundation for building user-customizable pages.  Beware that you'll still need to handle occasional syntax errors from your users.

Comment: Thanks, I have evaluated django template engine, it is very nice. It even not allow user to access attributes that begin with "_", so that it is safe enough to allow user to use it.

Comment: Another feature of the Django template engine that comes in handy here is that you can set the "alters_data" attribute on any function or object method, and that will prevent it from being called in a template.

Answer (score 5):

Jinja2 is a Django-ish templating system that has a sandboxing feature. I've never attempted to use the sandboxing, but I quite like Jinja2 as an alternative to Django's templates.  It still promotes separation of template from business logic, but has more Pythonic calling conventions, namespacing, etc.

[Jinja2 Sandbox](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/sandbox)

Comment: Jinja really rocks. I like the possibility to define macros (are a lot like functions) from within the templates. {{ navitem(text, link) }}

Comment: Good suggestion - the URL no longer works, but this works for the 3.0 series: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/sandbox/

Answer (score 0):

In rails there's something called [liquid](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/). You might take a look at that to get some ideas. Another idea: at the very least, one thing you *could* do is to convert your objects into simple dictionary - something like a json representation, and then pass to your template.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is probably "you can't".

The best you can probably do is to trap the individual users in virtual machines or sandboxes.